# Are there any other surfaces of constant width constructed from Platonic solids?

Tags: solid-geometry, platonic-solids

Watching videos about [Reuleaux polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_polygon), it is neat to see that the triangle is not the only polygon that creates a shape of constant width. Actually, a shape of constant width can be created from any odd sided polygon by rounding the edges.

When moving to 3D, a solid of constant width can be made by making a solid of revolution from Reuleaux polygons, but more surprisingly there is a solid of constant width that is derived from a Platonic solid, specifically by rounding a tetrahedron (AKA [Meissner tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuleaux_tetrahedron)).

Can there be any solid of constant width constructed from other Platonic solids? Can a Meissner octahedron be made? If yes, what is the condition for the number of faces? If not, why is the tetrahedron the only one?

I have seen some models of Reuleaux dodecahedra but I am not sure if it is a true shape of constant width. Example:
[image]
taken from [grabcad](https://grabcad.com/library/reuleaux-dodecahedron-1).

Comment: From the wiki page: "One can find repeated claims in the mathematical literature that the Reuleaux tetrahedron is analogously a surface of constant width, but it is not true: the two midpoints of opposite edge arcs are separated by a larger distance." It can be modified to make it a Meissner solid though.

Comment: The other platonic solids have vertices opposite vertices, so you have the same problems as with polygons with an even number of sides.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I have taken the Meissner/Reuleaux difference into account in the question, thanks

Comment: The rounded dodecahedron in the new picture is clearly not of constant width, as opposite faces are closer together than opposite vertices. It could be that the faces have a curvature radius roughly equal to the diameter of the solid itself, i.e. the curvature of the faces is half that of the circumscribed sphere. (I'm ignoring the extra rounding of edges and vertices for now.) You could call that a Reuleaux solid of some kind, but obviously opposing points in two opposite faces vary in distance - the face centres are closer together than points closer to the vertices.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis do you want to write a formal answer?